# Error message when compile and it may be something is wrong in my .php file

Tags: java, php, android, sql

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for Success
org.json.JSONException: No value for Success
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(JSONObject.java:410)
```

I got this error and it wont fetch data from my database.

this is my php file

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("", "",     "", "");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["age"] = $age;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);?>
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong with it. I have tried so many things.

this is the code block that have the errors

```
  Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("Success");

                        if (success) {
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong code block. Are you trying somewhere to convert the response to a json object? Error says for example `at org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(JSONObject.java:410)`

Comment: json is case sensitive ...

Comment: im sorry. im new to this. it doesn't show any error at the code. I read lot of thread saying that i may have error in my php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSON is case sensitive.**

You are returning the value of "success" i.e.,

```
$response["success"] = true;
```

But trying to fetch the value of "success" i.e.,

```
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("Success");
```

that's why it's resulting in error

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for Success
```

So use the **same case** in both the codes.